# ICMPv4/v6 redirect pkt received but route table not updated?

Tags: linux, networking, ipv6, freebsd, icmp

In FreeBSD/Linux, the **ICMPv4/v6 Redirect** pkt can be received by the OS, but the route table will not be changed accordingly?

I have enabled the necessary sysctl variables under /proc to accept the redirect pkt.

Any suggestion?

Comment: What are your exact settings for `accept_redirects` and `secure_redirects`?

Comment: Thanks for all the comments and answers. The reason why the route table doesn't change is that for security concern, FreeBSD/Linux will only process the icmp redirect pkt with the same src address as its default gateway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux you can check the setting for eth0 with:

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/eth0/accept_redirects
```

You can change the setting manually with:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/eth0/accept_redirects
```

or

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/accept_redirects
```

If you want to change this permanently you can add the following to `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_redirect = 1
```

I think redirects are accepted by default, so maybe they are turned of somewhere? It is possible that your `/etc/sysctl.conf` contains the line

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_redirect = 0
```

If it does, just remove it or change it to `... = 1`